# why this type of static variables in the loading don't need to call a static block of code

Tags: java, static

```
public class StaticTest {

    public static int k = 0;
    public static StaticTest t1 = new StaticTest("t1");
    public static StaticTest t2 = new StaticTest("t2");
    public static int i = print("i");
    public static int n = 99;
    public int j = print("j");

    {
        print("构造块");
    }

    static {
        print("静态块");
    }

    public StaticTest(String str) {
        System.out.println((++k) + ":" + str + " i=" + i + " n=" + n + " this:" + this);
        ++n;
        ++i;
    }

    public static int print(String str) {
        System.out.println((++k) + ":" + str + " i=" + i + " n=" + n);
        ++i;
        return ++n;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StaticTest("init");
    }
}
```

the source code as above,I knew the class loading order，which is **static variable >> static block of code >> member variable >> tectonic block of code >> tectonic method** .what confused me was that when

> public static StaticTest t1 = new StaticTest("t1");

executed,why the static block of code not ran

> static{
> print("静态块");
> }

but

> public int j = print("j");

ran? what was happened in it? I hope you could tell me something,I'll appreciate it.

Comment: The static variable is being initialized, so the constructor will be run. What would you expect to happen?

Comment: Can you *simplify* this code to specifically the one thing you're trying to demonstrate, and specify the exact output you're seeing?

Comment: Are you quite sure that the exact code you posted here actually compiled?

Comment: I have compiled and run it. @LewBloch

Comment: My mistake. I think I confused the `i` and `j` declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont do a `static call` there. The `new Object()` "method" calls the `constructor` and is never `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Output from your program:

```
1:j i=0 n=0
2:构造块 i=1 n=1
3:t1 i=2 n=2 this:mypackage.StaticTest@6d06d69c
4:j i=3 n=3
5:构造块 i=4 n=4
6:t2 i=5 n=5 this:mypackage.StaticTest@7852e922
7:i i=6 n=6
8:静态块 i=7 n=99
9:j i=8 n=100
10:构造块 i=9 n=101
11:init i=10 n=102 this:mypackage.StaticTest@4e25154f
```

You are correct that Java embarks on doing the static initializations first, from the top, before invoking the `main` method. Things are getting a little more complicated when you do

```
public static StaticTest t1 = new StaticTest("t1");
```

At this point, even though the static initializtions are not complete, the creation of the `t1` instance begins. I don’t think I would ever dare rely on someting like this working in my code. Anyway, construction of `t1` involves initializing `j` and running the non-static initializer block (`print("构造块");`) and the constructor; this produces lines 1 through 3 in the output. Construction of `t2` produces lines 4 through 6.

Static initialization continues with `i` (line 7), `n` and then the static initializer block (line 8).

Finally `main()` is invoked, creating one more object, which in turn gives you lines 9 through 11.

Comment: yeah,I got your point and i realized that when create a static variable with instance of StaticTest .JVM would allocate space in the heap for it,How did JVM know how big space to allocate?There is a assumption from me that only member variable would be allocated space(static variable and static block of code in a method area allocated space),so static block of code would not be called after **t1**  instanced,rather than **public int j = print("j")** ran,Am i right?

Comment: The way I think of it: static variables are allocated once when the class is loaded (there’s probably more to be said about it). Only instance variables are allocated with `new`, and it’s decided already on compile time how much space to allocate for them.

Comment: Static member variables can be assigned `new` objects. Why not?

Comment: Alright, I admit In my classic implementations of the Singleton pattern I have instantiated my static `theOneAndOnlyInstance` field in the declaration.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your answer,I get it from you. According to the class loading order,when the class is loaded into **Memory**,JVM has already knew what is static(variable,method..etc) and what is non-static and another class information too,While the key **new** comes out,JVM knows that the class has loaded,static block of code(it will be ran only once) would only run binding for _loading of StaticTest_,So it will not ran for static variable instantiation.This is my another guess about it,I hope to hear from you!

Comment: Correct, mostly. If I understand what you mean by “While the key **new** comes out,JVM knows that the class has loaded”, this is not correct when you use `new` in the static initialization like in your example. In this case the instance initialization happens when the static initialization is not complete. You are perfectly correct that any static block will be run only once. I don’t know if I can add anything else.